# Convert JSX to JS in C# using Babel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have the reactjs nuget packages and they're working as expected.

I want to transpile to js from the jsx syntax on the server side using a string I retrieved from the database, rather than from a .jsx file.

`React` has a `Babel` class in C# (using React Core in .net MVC Core app). However, it is not apparent how to use this manually. I imagine that React is simply getting the string value of the .jsx files and converting so this should be rather straightforward... though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [react.net](https://reactjs.net) to do that as follows.

```
string jsCode = ReactEnvironment.Current.Babel.Transform("<div/>");
```

This will return converted JS code as a string.

Comment: is there any way to specify input javascript version and output javascript version? my script was not converted in its online version until I checked "stage-2"